# Overlap one text string in the bottom of the other

Tags: pdftex, vertical-alignment

It is possible to overlap and left-align text by using `\rlap{text1}text2`; however, how to overlap (write text2 below text1) `text1` in the bottom (exactly centered) of `text2`?

For example:
`blabla \rlap{\quad 2} \underline{\hspace{1cm}} bla \rlap{\, text1}text2 \underline{\hspace{3.3cm}} bla  \rlap{\, bla} \underline{\hspace{2.7cm}}\\`

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your request. Could you provide a picture of what you want?

Comment: @SandyG

Add a picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\parbox`es:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\specialtext}[3]{%
  % #1 = width
  % #2 = text on top
  % #3 = text below
  \parbox[t]{#1}{%
    \parbox[b]{#1}{\centering#2\vskip1pt\hrule}%
    \vskip 1pt
    \nointerlineskip
    \centering\scriptsize#3%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

blabla \specialtext{1cm}{2}{} bla \specialtext{3.3cm}{text1}{text2}
bla \specialtext{2.7cm}{blabla2}{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `stackengine`:

[image]

You can change the thickness `{.5pt}` or the height `[-.5pt]` of the line.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stackengine}

\begin{document}

blah \stackunder{\stackon{\rule[-.5pt]{2cm}{.5pt}}{text 1}}{\scriptsize text 2} blah

\end{document}
```